# Tensorflow: sparse_tensor_dense_matmul slower than regular matmul

Tags: tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I have 2 scenarios:

```
scenario 1:
op: sparse_tensor_dense_matmul
A: 1000x1000 sparsity = 90%
B: 1000x1000 sparsity = 0%

scenario 2:
op: matmul
A: 1000x1000 sparsity = 0%
B: 1000x1000 sparsity = 0%
```

I understand that GPUs do not compute sparse matrix multiplication well but I would certainly expect them to perform it atleast as well as they perform non-sparse matrix mulipliation. In my code I get 10x slower for sparse_tensor_dense_matmul!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time
import itertools

rate = 0.1
N = 1000
itrs = 1000

num = int(rate * N * N)

combs = np.array(list(itertools.product(range(N), range(N))))
choices = range(len(combs))
_idxs = np.random.choice(a=choices, size=num, replace=False).tolist()
_idxs = combs[_idxs]
_idxs = _idxs.tolist()
_idxs = sorted(_idxs)

_vals = np.float32(np.random.rand(num))
_y = np.random.uniform(low=-1., high=1., size=(N, N))
_z = np.random.uniform(low=-1., high=1., size=(N, N))
################################################
x = tf.SparseTensor(indices=_idxs, values=_vals, dense_shape=(N, N))
y = tf.Variable(_y, dtype=tf.float32)
z = tf.Variable(_z, dtype=tf.float32)

sparse_dot = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(x, y)
dot = tf.matmul(z, y)
################################################
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
tf.local_variables_initializer().run()

start = time.time()
for i in range(itrs):
    [_sparse_dot] = sess.run([sparse_dot], feed_dict={})
total = time.time() - start
print (total)

start = time.time()
for i in range(itrs):
    [_dot] = sess.run([dot], feed_dict={})
total = time.time() - start
print (total)
################################################
```

25.357680797576904

2.7684502601623535

Comment: I tried executing your code in Google Colab, both with CPU and GPU as Runtime but I've observed that the execution times for both the operations you mentioned are same. Can you please provide more information, so that it can be reproduced. Here is the Gist of my [Executed Code](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/rmothukuru/b4323db6ce49a880d039ce8cafe20d67/so_54974492.ipynb). Thanks!